# Failed to compile - React router dom parsing error

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Not to sure why I'm getting this error with react router dom. I'm trying to create react routes however I'm getting a Failed to compile error as shown below.

```
/src/App.js
  Line 31:5:  Parsing error: Expected corresponding JSX closing tag for <Route>

  29 |     <Cart/>
  30 |     <Default/>
> 31 |     </Switch>
     |     ^
  32 | 
  33 |    </React.Fragment>
  34 |
```

App.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar'
import Product from './components/Product'
import ProductList from './components/ProductList'
import Details from './components/Details'
import Cart from './components/Cart'
import Default from './components/Default'




function App() {
  return (
   <React.Fragment>
     <h3>Hello from app</h3>

    <Navbar/>

    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" component={ProductList}>
      <Route path="/Details" component={Details}>

    <ProductList/>
    <Details/>
    <Cart/>
    <Default/>
    </Switch>

   </React.Fragment>

  );
}
```

I have used the Router in the index. file to keep the code cleaner.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>

  <React.StrictMode>

    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
  </Router>

  ,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

// If you want your app to work offline and load faster, you can change
// unregister() to register() below. Note this comes with some pitfalls.
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because preventing the restrictions by adding garbage is counter productive. Instead add more info around your question. What are you trying to achieve and why?

Comment: My herooooo!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me like you forgot to close the `<Route>.` Can you try closing the **Route** components like this?

```
  <Route path="/" component={ProductList} />
```